# How to view log or text files of remote computer in browser?

Tags: linux, monitoring, logs, log-analysis

I have a remote Linux server on which some java applications are running and they are generating some log files.

I don't want to give my users direct access to the server and files.
So is there any way, through my users can just see the log files in their local machine browser?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a vague, but I think I know what you are asking.  You could set up an Apache web server to allow directory listing and set the log files to be in the served directory (default on Linux is /var/www).  This would publish the log files publicly and all users would be able to download all files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As per your answer my users can download the files but afterwards they have to open then in some editor to view. I want my users to read the files directly in their browser. Is there any way?

Comment: Most browsers will render pure text files.  You could also get a browser based text editor.  See https://icecoder.net/